# What means : the function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ is closed?

Tags: real-analysis

What means : the function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ is closed ? In some book, they define $f$ is a closed function as $f(F)$ is closed whenever $F$ is closed, and in some other, they define it as $f$ is closed if the graph $\{(x,f(x))\mid x\in \mathbb R^2\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R$.

So what is the correct definition ? Both are equivalent ?

Answer (score 1):

They are not equivalent. A function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ has closed graph if and only if it is continuous, but a continuous function does not necessarily send a closed set to a closed set. For instance, the map $(x,y) \mapsto \text{arctg(x)}$ is continuous and sends the closed set $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$, which is not closed. Hence the two properties do not identify the same class of functions $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$.

I usually see the word "closed" attributed to those functions sending closed sets to closed sets.

Comment: I think that the first claim is false. Given $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, there is no equivalence between $f$ has closed graph and $f$ is continuous. Here is a counter-example :
$f(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{xy}$ if $xy\neq0$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise.
$f$ is discontinuous but has closed graph (which is the union of six closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Comment: On the other hand, it's true that the continuity of $f$ implies that it's graph is closed.